# Pass position in ListView to child RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, parameter-passing, adapter

I've got a layout with the ListView which contains child RecyclerView inside every item. The problem is to pass to Recycler Adapter its position in List. I've tried addind to add Tag to view in List getView() and then get it back from ViewGroup parent in onCreateViewHolder() of Recycler, but the tag was null. Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Multiple `RecyclerView`s inside a `ListView`? consider changing your design as it is not a best idea to have scrollable view inside another scrollable view

Comment: ListView is scrolling vertical, recycler - horizontal

Comment: why not use recyclerview instead of listview like google play store

Comment: Assuming that you are creating childview adapter inside listview getView() method , I think you can pass that position in adapter constructor no. Is there any problem for that?

Comment: Why don't you use recyclerview instead of listview?

Comment: @NaveenShriyan, yeah that works fine. Thanks. I'm blaming myself for missing such straightforward  solution...

Comment: Can i put that as an answer below can you upvote ?

Comment: @Naveen Shriyan, of course)

Comment: @Сергій Петренко: Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do in this way :**
Assuming that you are creating childview adapter inside listview `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method , I think you can pass that "**position**" in child adapter constructor.